# Multiple Mutable Array in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

i am fresher in ios, can any one tell me that how i manage multiple mutable array? for eg: i have 3 array  in that one array is for image and other two array contain name and description and i want to display on UITableView cell

i have try this but it crash.

```
image = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"demo_business_image@.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo_business_image@.png"], nil];
name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dinner Bell Annouse 50% Discount on Punjabi Food!", nil];
time = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"13M", nil];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return image.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:720];
    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:721];
    UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:722];
    img.image = [image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    lbl1.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    lbl2.text=[time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is the crashing error?

Comment: Can you please post you crashlog here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
image=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"demo_business_image@.png"], nil];
name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Dinner Bell Annouse 50% Discount on Punjabi Food!", nil];
time=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"13M", nil];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
 {
 return image.count;
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 UIImageView *img=(UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:720];
 UILabel *lbl1=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:721];
 UILabel *lbl2=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:722];
 img.image=[image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 //    lbl1.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    lbl2.text=[time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (cell == nil)
{
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There image Array count was 2.But in name and Time array 1 object only is there.So you have to give the same size for three arrays.

Comment: ya i have done that but i have take one NSMutableDictionary and store all there array into it    .but it crash                                             data=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [data setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [data setObject:image  forKey:@"image"];
    [data setObject:dis  forKey:@"discrip"];

Comment: Create the dictionary like this

NSDictionary *DIc=[NSDictionary DictionarywithObjectsAndkeys:[UIImage imageNamed:@"demo_business_image@.png"],@"Image",@"Dinner Bell Annouse 50% Discount on Punjabi Food!","Name",@"13M",@"Time",nil];

And store Dic object in nsmutable array

NSMutableArray *Arr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[Arr addObject:Dic];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{return image.count;}
```

image.count result was 2 value(value from image array) from your coding,
when  cellForRowAtIndexPath called 2 times for every arrays
but in other arrays have 1 value only, it must show error index of bound array

Answer (score 0):

In your code the image count is 2 so change the ,as the cell will be created 2 time according to number of section in table view because the name  & time array contain only 1 objects each so add an equal number of objects in both NSMutableArray.

Than you will get the expected output. Or you can try for NSDictionary with key values pairs.